# can't draw "chart_Series" graph in loop "quantmod package"

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I just installed the latest version of R and installed the latest version of Rstudio and ran into an interesting problem.

It turned out that I can draw one graph

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)

getSymbols('AAPL',src='yahoo')
AAPL <- tail(AAPL,200)

chart_Series(AAPL[sample(1:200,20)])
```

but I can't draw multiple graphs in sequence in a loop

```
for(i in 1:10){
  chart_Series(AAPL[sample(1:200,20)]) 
}
```

there is no error, i just get a blank screen[image]

There are no problems with a regular plot()

```
for(i in 1:10){
  plot(rnorm(100)) 
}
```

session

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default





time zone: Asia/Damascus
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4.22 TTR_0.24.3      xts_0.13.1      zoo_1.8-12     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0 tools_4.3.0    curl_5.0.0     grid_4.3.0    
[5] jsonlite_1.8.4 lattice_0.21-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `print` to return the plots like this:

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)

getSymbols('AAPL',src='yahoo')
AAPL <- tail(AAPL,200)

for(i in 1:10){
  print(chart_Series(AAPL[sample(1:200,20)])) 
}
```

Comment: But in the older version of quantmod, you didn't need  add the print() command, right? Why was it added?